# mongoDB not returning objs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Trying to follow a tutorial regarding mongoDB in angularJs, I've managed to insert data on mongoDB via commandline however when I try to call the obj back on angular server.js it's not returning me anything. Not sure if my server.js is even connected to my mongoDB though mongo is running, how can I make sure its connected to my mongoDB?

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('userDB', ['userDB']);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


app.get('/userDB', function (req, res){
    console.log('I receive a GET req.');
    db.userDB.find(function(err, data){
        console.log(data + 'send me something back');
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Angular service, this is not returning my anything as well guess there's no connection yet.

```
function _getUser() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/userDB'
        })
    }

var getUsers = function (id){
            homeService.getUsers()
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
```

Comment: implement some error handling to avoid all this guess work

Comment: that console.log("send me back"..) is returning on my cmd just not the data from userDB

Comment: ok. what about the arguments?

Comment: sorry i'm lost, arguments? none of the data, res are returning. not sure how else I'm going to debug it apart from console.log. Is there a way to check if server.js is connected to my mongo?

Comment: tried mongoClient.connect, which is on mongodb doc to see if its connected when there's no error and it returning me that its connected.

Comment: check the network tab in chrome see what the response body looks like and the request headers and payload

Comment: well its now returning me the obj on http request, but the db.userDB.find() is returning me [object object].